# ¿Cómo guardar el response de una Promesa dentro de una variable?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un request GET con javascript vanilla desde un .html, y estoy buscando guardar el resultado del request dentro de una variable, ya que esta data la voy a manipular dentro de este .html, sin embargo con mi código no obtengo un response si no un **Promise {pending}**

Este es mi código:

```
let products = fetch('http://localhost/api/products')
        .then(response => response.json())


console.log(products)
```

Answer (score 1):

El tema de las promesas no es fácil ¿verdaad?, bueno solo al principio.
Ten en cuenta que **fetch** no devuelve un valor por si misma, sino la promesa (promise) de que va a darte un valor. Ese valor lo recoges a través del método **then**. En tu ejemplo sería algo así

```
fetch('http://localhost/api/products')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
```

El tema de las promesas es algo más amplio, pero este es el uso básico.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero ando buscando asignar el response a una variable ya que despues si quiero hacer un response.nombre fuera del fetch lo pueda hacer sin problemas, pero no lo he logrado.

Comment: Así, sin ser muy sofisticados, podrías asignar data a una varible de ámbito global para que puedas usarla fuera del fetch.

Comment: ya lo intente declarando var repuesta = null, pero console log me imprime null ya que el fetch es asincrono y por ende es lo ultimo que se ejecuta y por eso no puedo asignar el valor de la response a null

Answer (score 0):

El uso de promesas es de las cosas mas complicadas para principiantes, [aqui te dejo](https://medium.com/@jmz12/callbacks-promesas-y-async-await-que-alguien-me-explique-514137cb57e2)  un articulo que explica como funciona las promesas. En cuanto a tu código te dejo un ejemplo básico.

```js
// se declara funcion asyncrona
async function myFuncion() {

  // se usa await para que el resultado de la promesa 
  // se mantenga en el contexto de la funcion
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  
  // convertimos a json
  const jsonrsponse = await response.json()
  console.log(jsonrsponse)
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFuncion()">click</button>
```